# Learn Python The Hardway ex24

Tags: python, string

Quick question to make sure I understand correctly.

1) By defining `val = 1000`, and then `a, b, c = secret_formula(val)` the `secret_formula(started)` uses the `a, b, c` variable (which calls `val`) for the **started** argument

2) the `secret_formula` then stores the 3 return values which is used going forward

```
def secret_formula(started):
    jelly_beans = started * 500
    jars = jelly_beans / 1000
    crates = jars / 100
    return jelly_beans, jars, crates

val = 10000
a, b, c = secret_formula(val)

print "With a starting point of: %d" % val
print "We'd have %d beans, %d jars and %d crates." % (a, b, c)

d = secret_formula(10)

print "we can also do that this way:"
print "Wed have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crates." % d
```

Comment: Which version of python are you using.  What is secret_formula(1)?

Comment: Please do note that LPTHW is not the recommended resource to learn Python. You should rather read for example [How to Think Like a Computer Scientist: Learning with Python 2nd Edition](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch05.html).

Comment: ***PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE*** close the LPTHW website **right now** and find another resource. It absolutely sucks. While you may accidentally end up learning some useful things, you'll need to unlearn much more.

Comment: Oh right, why is it so bad ? I will check out that other one Antti Thnaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by - *then `a, b, c = secret_formula(val)` the secret_formula(started) uses the a, b, c variable (which calls val) for the started argument* .

But when you do - `a, b, c = secret_formula(val)` - it *calls* the function `secret_formula()` with parameter `val` , which basically means that it starts executing the function `secret_formula()` with `started` variable having the value (reference of same object, though I wouldn't go into there yet) of `val` .

Then after the function is completed and it returns a value , using `return` statement, the returned value is assigned to `a,b,c` . When you do -

```
a, b, c = <something>
```

That something has to be an iterable (like a list or a tuple) that gives three elements (so in case of `list` or `tuple` , it has to be a list of tuple of three elements) . Then it stores the first value in `a` , second value in `b` , third in `c` . More details about the assignment statement can be found in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) .

When you do - `return jelly_beans, jars, crates` - it internally returns a tuple of three elements.

When you do -

```
d = secret_formula(10)
```

`d` completely stores the returned tuple.

Comment: I have played with ** print "Here is %d %d %d" % d ** and it needs the three %d's to print into.. Thanks

Comment: yes , because of how the `%` formating works, it can accept a single value or tuples on the right side . If you want to print the tuple as is , you need to do - `print "Here is tuple - %s' % (d,)` (Just FYI)

Answer (score 1):

`secret_formula` is called on `val`, which has a value of 10000, so `secret_formula` runs with with its `started` argument being equal to 10000. It uses the 10000 value for `started` to calculate the values of `jelly_beans`, `jars` and `crates` and returns the values of all three of those variables. Since `a`, `b` and `c` (3 variables) are set to the return value of `secret_formula`, they receive the values that were stored in `jelly_beans`, `jars` and `crates` inside `secret_formula`.

The basic structure for setting a variable equal to the return value of a function is this:

`my_outside_variable = my_function(value_going_into_function)`

Answer (score 1):

Overall idea is correct, but `a, b, c` does not call the function or the input to it, at least that's what you make it sound.

The order of operation is `secret_formula(val)` get executed by calling the function. Since 3 `return` values were given `jelly_beans, jars, crates`, they're assigned to `a, b, c` respectively.

This can be checked by `print "We'd have %d beans, %d jars and %d crates." % (a, b, c)` as you have it in the code.

Whereas `d` gets a list of those values since only one variable was assigned.

However, you cannot assign two variables when calling the function, you must have either 3 (one gets each return), or 1 (get a list).